# How to disable ES modules/bundle files on dev in Vite?

Tags: vite, esbuild

When building our frontend in a fairly large repo we end up with *a lot* of files, which slows down the network tab of devtools significantly - to a point where it's barely usable after a few refreshes.

Is there a setting in Vite that bundles everything in dev mode/disables ES modules?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why Vite is slow with your setup with not having the vite.config.js.

But if you want a dev mode with bundling you could you use:

```
npx vite build --watch --minify=false & npx vite preview
```

also you would probably want to turn off treeshaking with:

```
build.rollupOptions.treeshake: false
```

Note that live reload doesn't work in that case, only rebundling, so you should either reload the page yourself or use some live reloader to watch your `dist` folder.

You can vote for adding the live preview in Vite here:

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5196

Comment: Thanks! Vite itself is pretty fast, but chrome devtools absolutely seem to give up with the amount of files we have.

I'll give your suggestion a go and report back.

It sounds like there's no configuration way that'd just allow me to change this instead of using rollup?

Comment: @Jonas Vite isn't a bundler, it uses rollup for that. if my answer will solve your problem, don't forget to accept it (the checkbox) and upvote (the arrow up), thanks

Comment: I was hoping there is an option to tell esbuild to bundle everything up rather than using es modules - according to the [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io/api/#bundle) docs that option exist but I (seemingly) can't get it to have an effect

Comment: @Jonas i guess there could be no difference which bundler to use. and yes, Vite's dev mode works specifically with ESM